# How can instructors bridge the gap between an engineering course in stochastic systems and a more rigorous Stochastic Processes course?

Tags: probability, engineering-mathematics

Systems and electrical engineering graduate students often take a course on stochastic systems (a.k.a. "Probabilistic Systems Analysis").  A typical course will present such topics as multivariable probability distributions, auto- and cross-correlations (and Fourier transformations of them), Ergodicity, stationarity, etc.

Students wanting a more advanced treatment after completing the above often gravitate towards a more rigorous Stochastic Processes course in the math department, which normally smacks them over the head with the concept of Measure Theory, which throws them for a loop, even if some have taken a course in advanced engineering mathematics.

What is the best way to bridge the gap between what is a more applied treatment of these probabilistic concepts into the more abstract notions, particularly for students that may not have had a graduate-level Real Analysis course?

Related questions:

- [Best textbooks to introduce measure theory and Lebesgue integration?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/178/best-textbooks-to-introduce-measure-theory-and-lebesgue-integration/317#317)
- [Mathematical thinking skills for engineering students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2415/mathematical-thinking-skills-for-engineering-students)

Comment: That mismatch would mean they require an intermediate analysis course... I haven't seen *any* engineering calculus courses including measure theory, and most probability courses don't cover it either.

Comment: @vonbrand That was my impression as well.  Any paths between these two courses seem to require quite a bit of a mathematical detour that I think puts off most engineers, even though they would benefit greatly from the Stochastic Processes course.  Having more theory would never hurt anyone, but it's slightly impractical.